# How to save image into resource folder java swing

Tags: java, netbeans

I am trying to save a image file in a resource folder in netbeans but i am having problem to find the path of resource folder.

My code below:

```
JFileChooser fileChooser = new JFileChooser();
    FileNameExtensionFilter filter = new FileNameExtensionFilter("*.Images", "jpg", "gif", "png", "jpeg");
    fileChooser.addChoosableFileFilter(filter);
    int result = fileChooser.showSaveDialog(null);
    if (result == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
        path = fileChooser.getSelectedFile().getAbsolutePath();
        filename = fileChooser.getSelectedFile().getName();
         String fullPath = getClass().getResource("/resource").toString();
                                        System.out.println(fullPath);
        System.out.println(filename);
        System.out.println(path);
        Image img = null;
        try {
            img = ImageIO.read(fileChooser.getSelectedFile());

        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(AddItems.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        ImageIcon image = new ImageIcon(img.getScaledInstance(208, 104, 208),path);

        jlblImage.setIcon(image);

    } else {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "No file selected.");
    }
```

> Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
>       at com.gaurav.auctionhouse.view.AddItems.jImageBtnActionPerformed(AddItems.java:213)
>       at com.gaurav.auctionhouse.view.AddItems.access$000(AddItems.java:29)
>       at com.gaurav.auctionhouse.view.AddItems$1.actionPerformed(AddItems.java:99)
>       at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
>       at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2348)
>       at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
>       at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
>       at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
>       at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6533)
>       at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324)
>       at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6298)
>       at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2237)
>       at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4889)
>       at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2295)
>       at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
>       at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4889)
>       at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4526)
>       at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4467)
>       at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2281)
>       at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2746)
>       at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:758)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
>       at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>       at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
>       at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:90)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:729)
>       at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
private void jbtnSubmitActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    String itemname = jtxtItemName.getText();
    String category = jcboCategory.getSelectedItem().toString();
    String description = jtxtAreaDescription.getText();
    String reservedPrice = jtxtReservedPrice.getText();
    String image =filename;

    if (itemname.isEmpty() || category.isEmpty() || description.isEmpty() || reservedPrice.isEmpty() || image.isEmpty()) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "All fields are required.");
    }  else {
        Item item = new Item(category, description, reservedPrice, itemname, image);
         try {
             int i = itemdao.createItem(item);
             if(i> 0 ){
                 File sourceFile = new File(path);
                 File destinationFile = new File("resources/Image/"+ filename);
                 BufferedReader reader;
                 PrintWriter writer;
                 try {
                     reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(sourceFile));
                     writer = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(destinationFile));
                     reader.close();
                     writer.close();
                 } catch (Exception e) {
                     JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Failed to save Image");
                 }
                 //Paths.get(resource.toURI()).toFile();
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Successfully saved item");
             }
         } catch (SQLException ex) {
             JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ex.getMessage());
         }
    }
}
```